# Protection of APIM API and Azure Functions Apps using Authentication and RBAC via Azure AD and APIM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-api-management

Azure APIM exposes web APIs from an Azure Functions app, each web API request is authenticated using Azure AD, and each API request is based on RBAC via AAD.

Does Azure APIM and AAD support this? Any link would be appreciated.

**Update**

I am looking for a way where APIM can do both authentication and authorisation, if possible.

Comment: googling `azure api management azure ad authentication` gave me a lot of article to read...

Comment: yes, I did, but I cannot find it. I am looking for a way where APIM can do both authentication and authorisation.

Comment: Then could you explain a little bit more what you're trying to do ???

Answer (score 0):

Check below docs:

[Configure your App Service or Azure Functions app to use Azure AD login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad)

[Assign Azure roles for access rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/concept-enable-rbac#assign-azure-roles-for-access-rights)

Comment: I knew link 1, but it doesn't go through APIM. Is there a way that APIM can do both authentication and authorisation?